# Create world frame

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to use the [SVO](https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_svo/wiki/Run-SVO-with-ROS) package for Visual Odometry, so I need the world frame because it gives me the pose relative to that frame, but I'm not using it so I need to create it.

This is a simplified tf_frame graph of my project:

[image: image description]

and I would like to create a broadcast between odom and world, or between any frame and world. What do you suggest?

Edit: with the help of PeteBlackerThe3rd, now the rqt_tf_tree is:

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328674/create-world-frame/) by [Dylan](https://answers.ros.org/users/31995/dylan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2019-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't create individual frames in ROS you define the relationships between them. Looking at your tf_frame graph, the SVO package has already created by `world` frame by defining the relationship between the camera and the world.

Your problem here is that you have two unconnected TF trees, is the camera used by SVO either the bottom cam or front cam on your drone? If so then you simply need to update the name of the `cam_pos` frame used by SVO to match the appropriate camera on your drone. If it's a different camera then you need to create an additional static transform defining the position of that camera within your `ardrone_base_link` frame.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dylan](https://answers.ros.org/users/31995/dylan/) on 2019-07-17**:
Thanks for your answer! The camera used by the SVO package is the bottom camera of my drone. I couldn’t find where to change the cam_pos for ardrone_bottom_camera, or where to change the world frame. Do you recommend to change the cam_pos for the bottom camera’s node? How can I do that? Thanks

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-07-17**:
looking at the source code of the [visualiser node](https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_svo/blob/d6161063b47f36ce78252ee4c4fedf3f6d8f2898/svo_ros/src/visualizer.cpp), the frame_id `cam_pos` is hard coded into SVO. If you edit this code so that the frame_id is `ardrone_base_bottomcam` instead then it should link up your TF tree. Let us know how you get on.

**Comment by [Dylan](https://answers.ros.org/users/31995/dylan/) on 2019-07-17**:
I changed `msg.header.frame_id = "/world";` for `msg.header.frame_id = "/ardrone_base_bottomcam";` and the rqt_tf_tree is the same as the image I posted in the main post.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-07-18**:
You want to change `cam_pos` to `ardrone_base_bottomcam` not `world`. Also where did you change this? Finally if you don't see any change it sounds like you didn't re-build the appropriate package.

**Comment by [Dylan](https://answers.ros.org/users/31995/dylan/) on 2019-07-18**:
OK, now I understand perfectly. I pasted the new tf_tree in the main post. So, now the node svo makes the transformation between the bottom camera and another frame (it's called world, but I can change that name). But what does that mean?

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-07-18**:
Glad you've got these connected now. As for what it means, well. The SVO node will be updating the position of the world frame relative to your drone as it moves. Since this is odometry only it will be relative to the location of the drone when the SVO node was started.

**Comment by [Dylan](https://answers.ros.org/users/31995/dylan/) on 2019-07-18**:
The output topic of the SVO is `/svo/points` or `/svo/pose`? both give me the 6-grade pose, but /svo/pose just publishes once in a while, and /svo/points at a much higher rate. Those positions are the displacement between the starting position and the actual position?